# Set x increases by 1, Set y increases by 3. Need help with a function that will take $x_n$ and give me $y_n$

Tags: algorithms, functions

Two sets

```
x = 1,2,3,4,5...
y = 1,4,7,10,13...
```

I need to write a function

$f(x_n) = y_n$

I found that if I

1. take a number from x
2. double it
3. subtract 2
4. add the result to the original number
5. I get the corresponding number from y

Here's what I have so far (it's in ruby code), it works but is there a better way of doing it.

```
def f(x)
  if x > 1
    return x + ((2 * x) - 2)
  else
    return 1
  end
end

y = f(x)
```

Comment: Not sure what better way you are looking for. What you have seems fine, expect we can multiply by 3 instead of doubling and then adding itself. I guess Ruby does not have overflow issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your values y form what is called an arithmetic progression, namely a sequence where each element is obtained from the previous one just by adding always the same constant. In your case the constant is 3, namely:
1, 4=1+3, 7=4+3, 10=7+3 and so on.

Since the FIRST time you add 3 corresponds to x=2, the formula is just

y=1+3*(x-1)

or (equivalently)

y=3*x-2.

Comment: Wow thanks, I can't believe I didn't think about 3x instead of 2x + x lol.